# Multiplication of 2d arrays with different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes, multiplication

Novice in python, I'm trying perform an optimal interpolation and, somewhere in my code, I need to multiply two arrays as follow: Cgd * inv(Cdd)

### where:

=> Cgd: covariance array grid-data (792x2134) 
=> Cdd: covariance array data-data (2134x2134)

As you can see, the two arrays have different shapes. 
What is the most phytonic way to perform such calculation? (I am not sure about the np.dot operator)

thanks for all

Comment: In most cases finding the inverse of a matrix is completely unnecessary - what I get from what you're trying to do is solve a system of linear equations. There are many great algorithms for that. Just do what @behzad.nouri has said and it'll solve this problem and many more that you'd likely face otherwise ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [numpy.linalg.solve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve). It solves `Ax = b`, which gives `x = inv(A) b`, but this is more stable than solving for `inv(A)` and then multiplying it by `b`.

Comment: Actually, this is the equation I try to solve: **D = mean(data) + Cgd*inv(Cdd)*(data-mean(data))**, with data (2134 elems). Any guess how to write it correctly?

Comment: you can find `Cgd * inv(Cdd)` by `np.linalg.solve(Cdd, Cgd')`, and then taking transpose. `Cgd'` is transpose of `Cgd`.

Comment: Hi, thank you but I am still confused. Let's say I have `d = data-mean(data)`, I want to solve `Cgd*inv(Cdd)*d`, as you suggested i can start with `C = np.linalg.solve(Cdd, Cgd')`, next how to solve correctly the rest ? Thanks for your help :)